# A question in inverse Galois Theory

Tags: finite-groups, galois-theory, inverse-problems

Let $\mathbb{G}= \{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ be a finite group and $\rho$ its regular representation. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be indeterminates and let $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)^\top$. Let the matrix $G$ be defined through $G = (\rho(g_1)x,\dots,\rho(g_n)x)$ and let $A'$ be the matrix $A' = \text{diag}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Consider the matrix $A = G A' G^{-1}$.
Suppose there exists $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that

1. $\det(G(\alpha)) \neq 0$
2. $A = A(\alpha)$ has rational coefficients
3. the characteristic polynomial $X_A(t)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is it true that $\mathrm{Gal}(X_A(t) / \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{G}$?

I have written a proof down, but am a bit unsure about it and would be very happy if someone finds a different proof and shares it.

Edit:
I uploaded the proof. I would be very happy on your comments regarding if the proof is correct or not.
[Here is the link.](https://ia600507.us.archive.org/17/items/a_note_in_galois_theory/a_note_in_galois_theory.pdf)

Comment: Do you mean the splitting field of $X_A(t)$?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: Can you add an outline of your proof?

Comment: Yes I can upload the proof.

Comment: When you write $A(\alpha)$, you mean in the formula for $A$ substitute $\alpha_i$ for $x_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$? And when you ask about the "coefficients" of $A$, you mean the *entries* of $A$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.